# SQL null image to VARBINARY(MAX) Results in Empty

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Here is the scenario. We have a column of type `IMAGE` in a table that holds compressed data. This column can be null. In a different version, we moved this data to a separate table, still an image column.

We have a stored procedure that is checking where the data is, in the original table or the new table. To do that, it selects the value into a `VARBINARY(MAX)` variable, checks if it is null, if so grabs it from the new table.

Something strange is going on with the checks. For a few rows in the database, the column displays as `NULL`, but when cast to `VARBINARY(MAX)` it ends up being an empty value of 0x. This is only for 4 rows out of 426, all others evaluate to `NULL` fine. If you check for null in the table itself, like `WHERE <column> IS NULL` it evalulates to true, but if you do `WHERE CAST(<column> as VARBINARY(MAX)) IS NULL` it evaluates to false.

I can change around my stored procedure so that it handles correctly, but I'm a little baffled as to what is going on here. Any ideas?

This is on SQL Server 2005.

```
***edit to try and include a clearer example
e.g.
SELECT a
FROM Table
WHERE a IS NULL

SELECT a
FROM Table
WHERE CAST(a as VARBINARY(MAX)) IS NULL

the first query returns the result with NULL, the second query doesn't return anything.

Similarily, the stored procedure looks something like this:
DECLARE @CompressedData VARBINARY(MAX)

SELECT @CompressedData = imageColumn
FROM originalTable
WHERE ID = @ID

IF (@CompressedData IS NULL)
BEGIN
  SELECT @CompressedData = imageColumn
  FROM newTable
  WHERE ID = @ID
END
```

In that case, @CompressedData does not evaluate to NULL since it is getting a value of 0x

Comment: Stored procedure definition ?

Comment: what do you mean? like what does the stored procedure T-SQL look like?